# How to write a proper IF THEN Excel formula for specific use case?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out how to write a formula that will subtract C3 from D3 if D3 has a value, if no value I need it to subtract C3 from H3.

```
=TEXT(D3-C3, "h:mm:ss")
```

Example of report:
[image: EXAMPLE OF REPORT]

Comment: `=Text(If(D3<>"", D3-C3, H3-C3), "h:mm:ss")` should be about right.

Comment: `=IF(D3="",H3,D3)-C3` and format the cell as `h:mm:ss` instead of using the `TEXT` function.

Comment: Any reason why you don't post this as answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IF(D3="",H3,D3)-C3` and format the cell as `h:mm:ss` instead of using the TEXT function.